# Get 'active' file explorer and navigate to folder

Tags: c#, system.io.file, microsoft-file-explorer

My application creates a project in a database, and uses the returned project ID to create a folder on the server. The application is located in a folder 'projects 2021', and also creates the project folder there.

The user starts the application with windows file explorer by navigating to the 'projects 2021' folder and clicking the executable. What I would like to do is use this active windows file explorer to navigate to the newly created folder.

Is it possible to fetch the process or instance of file explorer from where the application was started, and then use that to navigate to a specific folder?

Comment: "The user starts the application with windows file explorer" - how do you know this to be true? How do you know that they didn't navigate once and pin it to the start menu or task bar? In general, making assumptions about *what users will do* or *what explorer windows they have open* just leads to broken code when the assumptions aren't true. Believe it or not, opening a new explorer window *doesn't* cost you $$$ each time it happens, and you're guaranteed to have one window opened where you want it (until the user interacts with it)

Comment: You are correct; It's not good to assume that an explorer window is open. What I mean to ask is if it is possible to fetch this info IF it has been opened that way (which I'm expecting to be 75% of the time). The fallback would be to open a new explorer window, which is what I already have right now